# Update the password issue in SharePoint 2010 FBA Claims Authentication using the sqlmembershiprovider

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, forms-authentication

In my SharePoint 2010 FBA, i have configured to use the asnetsqlmembershipprovider and created a  separate UI for user management,which does the add/edit/ forgotpassword  etc.
In the case of changing the password and apply a new password for employees of the company, its failed to do so.

below is my code fromw ebconfig:

```
<membership defaultProvider="OPMembership">
  <providers>
    <add name="OPMembership" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="OPAPP" connectionStringName="FBACON" enablePasswordReset="true" **enablePasswordRetrieval="false"** passwordFormat="Hashed" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="OPRoles">
  <providers>
    <add name="OPRoles" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" applicationName="OPAPP" connectionStringName="FBACON" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

it says opasswordretrieval=false .
Does that mean, i wont be able to give a mechanism to update the endusers of my custom fba web appln?

should i go with some other approach for passwordretrieval and update the password.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With enablePasswordRetrieval = false you can still change the password.  Simply call the ResetPassword method to get a new password for the account. You can then use the newly reset password to change the password on the account to any password you want.  Take a look at the ResetUserPassword code of the SharePoint FBA Pack, it does exactly that:

http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication/Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication/Code/Utils.cs

Comment: Thanks for the reply and link. Is there any way, i can change the password of the existing user , using sql  or t-sql approach? because that would be easier, instead of writing  c# code .

Comment: Check the stored procedures in the membership database (aspnetdb) - there are stored procedures for each of the operations you can call through the API. So yes, I think you should be able to call the stored procedures directly to do the update, but I haven't done so myself, so i'm not sure if there are issues with this.